# how to Print out the employee details having highest and second highest salary?

Tags: arraylist

csv file which has 3 entries of empname,emp id,designation and salary Robert,33,Manager,12000 Duval,23,Associate,6000 Kierron,33,AD,20000

From below code how to Print out the employee details having the highest and second highest salary?

```
enter code here
```

public class HighSalary {

```
public static void highSalary() throws IOException {
    String record;
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/Users/ak/Documents/emp.csv"));

    System.out.println("\t\t  Printing Employee Details of Highest & Second Highest Salary \n");

    System.out.println(" ------------------------------------------------------------- ");
    System.out.println("|   ID      Name                Age         Address           |");
    System.out.println(" ------------------------------------------------------------- ");

    List<List<String>> arlist = new ArrayList<>();

    int highestSal = 0;
    int secondSal = 0;

    while ((record = br.readLine()) != null) {

        String[] words = record.split(",");

        arlist.add(Arrays.asList(words));

        int salary = Integer.parseInt(words[3]);
        if (highestSal == 0) {
            highestSal = salary;
            secondSal = salary;
        }
        else if (salary > highestSal) {
            secondSal = highestSal;
            highestSal = salary;
        }
        else if (salary > secondSal || secondSal == 0) {
            secondSal = salary;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("highest salary: " + highestSal);
    System.out.println("second highest salary: " + secondSal);
    br.close();
}
```

}

```
enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

You may iterate the file, keeping track of the highest and second highest salary.  When assigning a new highest salary, the second highest should be assigned to the previous highest salary.  Also, you may store two strings for the metadata associated with the highest and second highest paid employees.

```
Integer highest = null;
Integer second = null;
String highEmp = "";
String secondEmp = "";

while ((record = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] words = record.split(",");
    arlist.add(Arrays.asList(words));

    int salary = Integer.parseInt(words[3]);
    if (highest == null) {
        highest = salary;
        second = salary;
        highEmp = record;
        secondEmp = record;
    }
    else if (salary > highest) {
        second = highest;
        secondEmp = highEmp;
        highest = salary;
        highEmp = record;
    }
    else if (salary > second) {
        second = salary;
        secondEmp = record;
    }
}

System.out.println("highest salary: " + highest);
String[] parts = highEmp.split(",");
System.out.println("Name: " + parts[0] + ", Age: " + parts[1] + ", Desig: " + parts[2]);
System.out.println("second highest salary: " + second);
parts = secondEmp.split(",");
System.out.println("Name: " + parts[0] + ", Age: " + parts[1] + ", Desig: " + parts[2]);
```

Comment: When i am adding 2 more entries, addition to 3 entries in csv file so in total I have 5 entries in csv file let say Chris 45,D, 95000 Kim 23,PA,3000, then your code is throwing an exception. java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3 –

Comment: @Kriss You have changed your CSV file structure between this question and your previous one.  I assume _four_ columns, the fourth of which is the salary (with the first three being name, age, and designation).  Show us the actual structure of your file please.

Comment: thats right, first col is name, second col is age, third col is design and fourth col is salary

Comment: _Don't_ paste any data here!  Edit your question!

Comment: i have modified the code but still getting the errorSystem.out.println("highest salary: " + highestSal);
  String[] parts = highEmp.split(",");
  System.out.println("Name: " + parts[0] + ", Age: " + parts[1] + ", Desig: " + parts[2] + ", Sal: " + parts[3]);
  System.out.println("second highest salary: " + secondSal);
  parts = secondEmp.split(",");
  System.out.println("Name: " + parts[0] + ", Age: " + parts[1] + ", Desig: " + parts[2] + ", Sal: " + parts[3]);

Comment: The problem is likely with your data, not my code.  There isn't much more I can say/do at this point.  You will have to try debugging what you have.